# Calling a void (View view) from another void in the same class

Tags: javascript, java, android, call, void

When i start my application, i want it to immediately load another void. How can i do that?

My code starts with:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assistent);
        }
```

I want it to call this void:

```
private void load(View view) {

//i want the code in this void to load when the activity starts.

}
```

How can i do that?

Something like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assistent);

        this.load();
        }
```

But when i try that, it just gives me an error message:
[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: load function requires a view as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

### View

> This class represents the basic building block for user interface
>   components. A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is
>   responsible for drawing and event handling. View is the base class for
>   widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons,
>   text fields, etc.).

<s>**No need**</s> to pass `View` parameter .In here `onCreate` does this .

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assistent);

        this.load();
        }

    private void load() 
    {

     // Add your stuff here

    }

   }
```

Comment: How can i go to the load void from an OnClickListener?

Comment: You need parameter .Show your approach (code) .I hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

the method `load` takes a `View` as a parameter. but you are calling it without any parameter. although it is highly discouraged to do similar things like you are doing but if you need to call this you can pass a View type as parameter or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call a method that requires you to put an instance of View inside.

```
private void load(View view){}
```

So in order to call this you have to do something like:

```
this.load(your view Instance);
```